# scrape website for iphone/mobile web app output

Tags: iphone, html, screen-scraping, mobile-phones

All,

I have an existing website, that uses a CMS. There are no modules that we like or seem fit
for IPhone/Android/Windows Mobile Safari/Chrome/IE website display available for the CMS.

Is there any open-source project out there that can scrape a html site output for mobile browsers on the fly, where minimal coding is required, and little or no changes required to the original logic?

eg. apache/CMS -> converter -> iphone/android/windows phone.

Thanks in advance for your comments.

-Jer

Comment: Which CMS are you using?

Comment: @BrianWillis , I use joomla, but the modules found do not meet all our requirements